# showing some extra digits while reading a file in c++ using ifstream, here is my code

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

```
if(role==2)
    {
        int arr;
        ifstream record("total.txt");
        record>>arr;
        record.close();
        string names[arr];
        int age[arr];
        ifstream file("names.txt");
        ifstream file0("ages.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<arr;i++)
        {
            getline(file, names[i]);
            file0>>age[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<arr;i++)
        {
            cout << left << setw(25)
            << names[i] << " " << age[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

here i am reading from two files names and ages. Total.txt contains a number which is number of persons.
Here is the output window:

[enter image description here][image: 1]

after 19 it is showing 0 and 6419936, i dont know why. These 2 numbers are not present in ages.txt. How to get rid of them?

Comment: The simple explanation would be that the number in `total.txt` is not correct. I.e. it is nine, when really you only have seven names and ages. Did you check that?

Comment: You do realise that `string names[arr]; int age[arr];` is not legal C++? In C++ array sizes must be compile time constants, but `arr` is a variable. The simplest legal code is to use a vector, e.g. `vector<string> names(arr); vector<int> age(arr);`

Comment: this ***for(int i=0;i<arr;i++)*** is looping out of the bounds of name and age array

Comment: thank you very much, yes you are correct. Number in total.txt was more than the data in names and ages. it was tacking the garbage value.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Are you sure?

Comment: @ArjundevMishra Another advantage of using vectors is that you can use the vector `push_back` method to add items to the vector. That way you can easily make the vector be the same size as the number of items read from the file. So there is no need to a separate `total.txt` file.